# How to port uint32_t in C to Windows 7 (32-bit)

Tags: c

Recently I have come across a program which contained data types like

```
uint32_t, uint32, uint64 etc.
```

Can I run the program in Windows 7 (32 Bit) without making any changes?
I use Code::Blocks 10.05 with MingW.

If changes are required, which data types can replace them?

Also I would like to know which standard of C defines uint32_t, uint32 etc?
Is it the so called gcc C?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are from `<stdint.h>`, a C standard header introduced with C99, I think.

If you don't have C99 or a compatible header already in your system, which you *really* should have and *really* should investigate, you need to re-create the definitions yourself.

To do this you need to introduce a bunch of `typedef`s:

```
typedef unsigned int uint32_t;
```

and so on, of course after verifying that `unsigned int` is indeed *exactly* 32 bits on your compiler.

But this shouldn't be necessary, I think even Visual Studio has enough C99 support now to provide this header.

Comment: stdint.h was indeed introduced with C99 and are part of the C standard ever since. So it doesn't make sense to replace these int types as the OP requested - on the contrary, various non-standard types should be replaced with the ones in stdint.h.

Comment: Since the questioner is using mingw, wouldn't it be better to `#include <stdint.h>` for the standard type and then typedef the non-standard `uint32` and `uint64`, rather than typedef the standard `uint32_t`? Avoids any trouble if a later change to the code means that `<stdint.h>` gets included anyway and your typedef clashes, also means you don't have to worry about that verification that `unsigned int` is the right size.